# How may I show an incomplete web application on Linkedin or on my resume?

Tags: github, linkedin

I'm developing a dynamic webpage. It's not complete but it's already running as regard to the core features; several technologies are involved: HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap, Javascript, Jquery, JSON, APIs, Ajax and so on...

I don't want to spread it around yet for I want to develop it more, nor to purchase a domain name yet, but I would like to put it online somewhere to include it to my Linkedin profile or resume, just to show my proficiency as regard to the technologies mentioned above.

I would preferably like it to be accessible through a shareable link instead than being visible to anyone through the search engines.

Which platform (Github etc....) do you recommend for my purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have it hidden from search engines - add a *robots.txt* with the following content:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

Place the [robots.txt](https://www.robotstxt.org/) in the root directory of your website/application.

---

To make it available for others to see at a competitive rate, put your site on Heroku or perhaps create a droplet on Digital Ocean for £5 a month. You do not need a domain for either.

- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) you name your app, and you get a Heroku subdomain that contains the name of your app (if I remember it correctly)
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) you can share the IP of your droplet and make sure you have default configuration file set if on Nginx - not sure about Apache as I do not use). Let me tell you that it looks more professional however if you use a domain (perhaps a subdomain that makes sense).

Alternatives to Heroku and Digital Ocean is [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) (slightly more expensive), or any other Web Hosting Provider you can think of (I don't like the dependency on them - that why I prefer the big 3s).

On [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/georg-friedrich-keferboeck/) you have a section titled "Accomplishments" -there you can list it under "Projects" perhaps? Unless you created your project at Uni, School or Work - then you may wish to share the link under the appropriate section.

The source I would share on [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.com/) - creating a public repository everyone has access too (which makes sense to supply if you wish to impress with your programming skill).

Most importantly highlight both - URL and Repository on your CV :)

Generally, Employers looking for Developers like to see your GitHub account to see how active you are and filter your contributions towards the community - it tells a lot about you as a developer. ;)